# Add href to .text output in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using firebase to get this data,
I'd like to add href tags to message.userName output

```
$('#winners').text('Winner:' + ' ' + message.userName + ' ' + ' '+ 'score:' + ' ' + message.score + ' ' + ' '+ 'Start time:' + ' ' + message.startTime + ' ' + ' '+ 'End time:' + ''     + message.endTime );
```

I've tried

```
$('#winners').text('Winner:' + ' ' + '<a href=\"scoreTracker.php?id='+message.userID +'\"> + '  message.userName + ' ' + ' '+ 'score:' + ' ' + message.score + ' ' + ' '+ 'Start time:'
+ ' ' + message.startTime + ' ' + ' '+ 'End time:' + '' + message.endTime + '<\a>' );
```

Comment: Did you try change .text() to .html()?

Answer (score 3):

To avoid XSS attacks (among other weird problems), append an anchor element and set its text.  This means you don't have to worry about escaping anything.

```
$('#winners').append([
  'Winner: ',
  $('<a>')
    .attr('href', 'scoreTracker.php?id=' + encodeURIComponent(message.userId))
    .text(
      message.userName + ' score: ' + message.score + ' Start time: ' + message.startTime + ' End time: ' + message.endTime
    )
]);
```

If your HTML gets much more complicated, might I suggest a JavaScript template engine?  I use [Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) for most projects, but there are many choices.

Comment: I think you are missing a closing parenthesis there: `encodeURIComponent(message.userId).text(`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use append() , or html()

```
$('#winners').append('Winner:' + ' ' + message.userName + ' ' + ' '+ 'score:' + ' ' + message.score + ' ' + ' '+ 'Start time:' + ' ' + message.startTime + ' ' + ' '+ 'End time:' + ''     + message.endTime );
```

this may help you to understand better :

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/

Comment: Careful... your answer opens them up to potential XSS attacks.

Comment: Where do I add the href in your above answer? I have to problems displaying the text.

Comment: Excuse me , are you warning me , or the one who asked the question ?!

Comment: i think brad answer is better than mine ( more secured ). i was about to fiddle an example but no need to.

Answer (score 0):

Both @Brad and @ProllyGeek are correct -- but @Brad's solution is best given the potential risk of XSS attacks. Here is his code, just cleaned up a bit for better readability. :)

```
$('#winners').append([
    'Winner: ',
    $('<a />')
        .attr('href', 'scoreTracker.php?id=' + encodeURIComponent(message.userId)
        .text(message.userName + ' score: ' + message.score + ' Start time: ' + message.startTime + ' End time: ' + message.endTime)
]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @jmdb.  I actually just edited it and cleaned it up a couple minutes ago.   Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can edit someone else's post if you'd like.

Comment: object has no method text is an error message I'm getting. tried .html in place of .text same error obect has not method 'html' any suggestions?

Comment: @user3052997: You should Brad's code, not this one. This one is incorrect, it should be `$('<a />')`, not `$('a')`. Though I don't think that this would throw such an error.

Comment: oh, snap -- didn't realize you could edit someone elses post. thanks @Brad!